# How to find the oldest email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Just what the title says, how do I find the oldest email in Gmail? I know ho to find the [oldest email from a specific person](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18581/1512), but I’m interested in finding the oldest email, regardless of the sender or the label/folder it resides in at the moment. How can I do this without manually going through each label?

Comment: No button, but it takes only 3t o 4 minutes to page-click (25email per page) back through 5500 emails, to start from the oldest.
Kill, archive or use.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*All Mail* includes all the mail.

1. Click on the **All Mail** button on the side bar.
2. Right next to the < > buttons you should see a link **1-100 of xx,xxx** → click on the link.
3. The drop down should give you two choices: newest and oldest; select **oldest**.
4. You should now be on the last page.

Note: if the *All Mail* label isn't on the sidebar, it can be added via: *Gear* → *Setting* → *Labels* → **show**.

Comment: I completely forgot about _All Mail_. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work if there are many emails with whatever filter criteria you're using. Instead, see the method offered by @prplhaz4

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be an "oldest" link in gmail anymore so using this link to go to a really big page number seems to work:

https://mail.google.com/mail/#search//p99999

Method taken from [systembash.com](https://systembash.com/find-your-oldest-messages-in-gmail/)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. It gives me an error `Invalid search query - returning all mail.`

Comment: You can still kinda do this, but the url now is `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/p1000`, just keep incrementing the p1000 until you hit the last page, it's not ideal, but it's faster then pressing the `>` on for the 100s+ pages you have to get through.